# laravel passport with nuxtjs

Tags: laravel, nuxtjs

I'm trying to send requests from nuxtjs frontend to laravel backend which authenticates users with laravel passport I wanted to follow [this](https://github.com/anohabbah/nuxt-laravel-passport-example/blob/master/README.md) only resource in the whole web about laravel passport with nuxtjs,  but it says

> Copy the example env file and populate it with values from laravel
>
> cp .env.example .env

, but I dont have `.env` file in my nuxtjs project! should I make one manually? or did I missunderstand what he meant?
and my other questions that I couldnt find any answer to it is, what should I do on the server side to make it accepts nuxtjs requests in this case? because in this example on github I didn't notice him done anything extra on laravel side all the job was on nuxtjs side.

this is the `.env.example` that should be copied in `.env`

```
LARAVEL_ENDPOINT='http://127.0.0.1:8000'
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_ID=
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET=
```

Comment: `cp .env.example .env` command copies .env.example and names it .env, and then you can fill in the .env with

Answer (score 0):

you MUST create the .env file by doing:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

as we know NuxtJS is the Frontend (client) and the Laravel is the Backend (server), where on NuxtJS POV:

```
// WHICH SERVER DO I TRY TO CONNECT 
LARAVEL_ENDPOINT='http://127.0.0.1:8000'

// THE CREDENTIALS I MUST PROVIDE TO THE SERVER
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_ID=
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET=
```

The `PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_ID`  and `PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET`  is generated by the Laravel Passport using this command `php artisan passport:client` on Laravel (backend) side to generate a credentials to used by your client, on this case is NuxtJS.

Try looking back to read the Laravel Passport (OAuth2) on their [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport)